# Get the first day and selected day of the month according to the selected date and month from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have  dataframe which contain the date and month as per below sample:

[image]

If I want to get the data between the first day and the selected day within the month instead of I sum all together, how should I script it?

example:
given date = '03/03/2022'
data should able to get 01/03/2022 til 03/03/2022

Comment: In [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it says **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question**.  This gets more responses since it allows responders to easily recreate your data by copy/paste rather than having to retype it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
####################### Recreate part of OP's dataframe ######################### 
from datetime import datetime
Month = ["March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April"]
Date = ["1/3/2022", "1/3/2022", "2/3/2022", "3/3/2022", "4/3/2022", "4/3/2022", 
        "1/4/2022", "1/4/2022", "1/4/2022", "2/4/2022", "3/4/2022", "3/4/2022", "4/4/2022",]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Month":Month, "Date":Date})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
#################################################################################


givenDate = "3/3/2022"
# Convert given date to correct datetime format
givenDate = datetime.strptime(givenDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
# Set the monthStart variable equal to the 1st of the given month and given year
# Then convert it to the correct datetime format
monthStart = datetime.strptime(f"1/{givenDate.split('/')[1]}/{givenDate.split('/')[2]}", '%d/%m/%Y')

# Find all the data between (and including) the first date of the given month and the given date
df[(df["Date"] >= monthStart) & (df["Date"] <= givenDate)]
```

Output:

```
    Month   Date
0   March   2022-03-01
1   March   2022-03-01
2   March   2022-03-02
3   March   2022-03-03
```

If you don't want to include the start of the month or the given date in your range, then you can remove the respective equals signs (e.g. `>=` becomes `>` and/or `<=` becomes `<`)

If the given date is guaranteed to be a string in your given format, then you can do all of this in just 2 lines of code:

```py
monthStart = datetime.strptime(f"1/{givenDate.split('/')[1]}/{givenDate.split('/')[2]}", '%d/%m/%Y')
df[(df["Date"] >= monthStart) & (df["Date"] <= givenDate)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. After that you can calculate the sum if needed.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'Month': ['March', 'March', 'March', 'April', 'April', 'April'], 
    'Date': ['01/03/2022', '02/03/2022', '20/03/2022', '01/03/2021', '02/04/2022', '03/04/2022'], 
    'Minor': ['Clutlery', 'Tops', 'Shoes', 'Tops', 'Shoes', 'Turf'], 
    'Major': ['Kitchen', 'Clothes', 'Clothes', 'Clothes', 'Clothes', 'Garden'], 
    'MTD': [1000, 100, 200, 200, 400, 800]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

given_date = '03/03/2022'
given_date = datetime.strptime(given_date, '%d/%m/%Y')

#updated to check for both month and year
new_df = df[(df['Date'].dt.month==given_date.month) & (df['Date'].dt.year==given_date.year) & (df['Date']<=given_date)]
print(new_df)
print('Sum MTD is', new_df['MTD'].sum())
```

Output:

```
   Month       Date     Minor    Major   MTD
0  March 2022-03-01  Clutlery  Kitchen  1000
1  March 2022-03-02      Tops  Clothes   100

Sum MTD is 1100
```

Comment: hi @beginofwork is my suggestion able to answer your question?